# Connecting to a wifi network while acting as an access point

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi (model 3 B+) acting as a wireless access point. I would like the pi to be able to connect to an available wifi network while remaining a wireless access point.

The use case for this would be as follows:

1. Connect to the access point from a laptop
2. From the laptop, navigate to `pi_ip_address:port` in a browser
3. From the browser, a list of available networks would be shown
4. From the browser, select an option and enter the password
5. From the Pi, connect to the selected network

Is this possible? If so, has anyone had success doing this and/or is there documentation available?

Thanks in advance